# How to validate identicard number format in google form regular expression

Tags: validation, numbers, expression, google-forms

I want to validate ID number format in srilanka. we have 2 id number formats

1st one has 9 characters followed by English letter either v or x Eg: 882784096v
2nd one has 11 characters only Eg 19881919123

I want add a field in google form to enter either of above ID numbers
I tired following regular expression but it failed

```
[0-9]{9,11}(?:[vVxX])$
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the following expression

```
[0-9]{9}[vVxX][0-9]{11}
```

Will validate IDs like: `882784096v19881919123` or `882723496X86751919123`

Or rather:

```
([0-9]{9}[vVxX])|([0-9]{11})
```

Will validate IDs like: `882784096v` or `86751919123`

Comment: ([0-9]{9}[vVxX]) only this part is working, but not the other ID type